# A problem from Hungerford

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $H$, $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$, let $(H, K)$ be a subgroup generated by elements $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}, h \in H, k \in K$.
Prove that if $(H, G') = {e}$ then $(H', G) = {e}$. ($H'$ denotes a commutator subgroup of $H$).

I feel that there is a simple calculation trick that I simply miss with this one , can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Hall-Witt identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Identities)
$$
[x, y^{-1}, z]^y\cdot[y, z^{-1}, x]^z\cdot[z, x^{-1}, y]^x = 1,
$$
or more simply its consequence, the [three-subgroup Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_subgroups_lemma):

> If $X, Y, Z$ are subgroups of the group $G$, then $[X,Y,Z]=1$ and $[Y,Z,X]=1$ imply $[Z,X,Y]=1$.

Here you take $X = Z = H$ and $Y = G$.